# Сommunicate server client C++

Tags: c++, opencv, server, udp, client

I am writing a network program in C ++. How it works:

1. The server streams video for the client in real time.
2. The client receives the video data.

I tried to set up sending and receiving messages (right during streaming). For this, I started the video in a separate thread.

Messages from the client to the server reach the server without any problems. But if you send messages from the server to the client, then firstly the video itself changes, and some kind of garbage is displayed.

How it works (no)
[image]

I understand that this is due to the fact that the client is constantly receiving messages (vide). But is it possible to somehow solve this problem?

Server code

```
#include "server.h"

int Server::open()
{
    WORD DLLVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 1);
    if (WSAStartup(DLLVersion, &wsaData) != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    int sizeofaddr = sizeof(addr);

    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(addrss);
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
    bind(server, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
    listen(server, SOMAXCONN);

    std::cout << "Listening..." << std::endl;

    client = accept(server, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, &sizeofaddr);

    if (client == 0) {
        std::cout << "Error #2\n";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Client Connected!\n";
    }
}

int Server::sendData(const char *buffer, int len)
{
    return send(client, buffer, len, NULL);
}

int Server::recvData(char *buffer, int len)
{
    return recv(client, buffer, len, NULL);
}

int Server::close()
{
    closesocket(server);
    std::cout << "Server is closed" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Server main

```
#include "server.h"

#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include "opencv2\video\background_segm.hpp"
#include <opencv2\video\tracking.hpp>

#include <Windows.h>
#include <thread>
#include <string>

#define FRAME_WIDTH 640
#define FRAME_HEIGHT 480
#define CLIENT_CLOSE_CONNECTION_SYMBOl '#'

cv::Mat cameraFeed;
int height, width, IM_HEIGHT, IM_WIDTH, imgSize;

bool is_client_connection_close(const char *msg)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(msg); ++i)
    {
        if (msg[i] == CLIENT_CLOSE_CONNECTION_SYMBOl)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void VideoSender(Server server)
{
    cv::VideoCapture cap(0);
    while (true)
    {
        cv::Mat frame, image;
        if (!cap.read(cameraFeed))
        {
            std::cout << "Video dont work" << std::endl;
            break;
        }

        height = cameraFeed.rows;
        width = cameraFeed.cols;
        IM_HEIGHT = FRAME_HEIGHT;
        IM_WIDTH = FRAME_WIDTH;
        resize(cameraFeed, cameraFeed, cv::Size(IM_WIDTH, IM_HEIGHT));
        imgSize = cameraFeed.total()*cameraFeed.elemSize();
        server.sendData(reinterpret_cast<char*>(cameraFeed.data), imgSize);

        imshow("Video_sending", cameraFeed);
        char button = cv::waitKey(10);
        if (button == 'q')
        {
            std::cout << "Stop sending video data..." << std::endl;
            cap.release();
            cv::destroyWindow("Video_sending");
            server.close();
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    Server server;
    server.open();

    std::thread th_video(VideoSender, server);

    while (true)
    {
    //sending message
        std::string msg1;
        std::getline(std::cin, msg1);
        int msg_size1 = msg1.size();
        server.sendData((char*)&msg_size1, sizeof(int));
        server.sendData(msg1.c_str(), msg_size1);

    //receive_message
        int msg_size;
        server.recvData((char*)&msg_size, sizeof(int));
        char *msg = new char[msg_size + 1];
        msg[msg_size] = '\0';
        server.recvData(msg, msg_size);
        std::cout << "Message from client: " << msg
            << " (size: " << msg_size << ")"
            << std::endl;
        delete[] msg;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Client code

```
#include "client.h"

int Client::open()
{
    WORD DLLVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 1);
    if (WSAStartup(DLLVersion, &wsaData) != 0) {
        std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    int sizeofaddr = sizeof(addr);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(addrs);
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
    if (connect(server, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0) {
        std::cout << "Error: failed connect to server.\n";
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << "Connected!\n";
}

int Client::sendData(const char * buffer, int len)
{
    return send(server, buffer, len, NULL);
}

int Client::recvData(char *buffer, int len)
{
    return recv(server, buffer, len, NULL);
}

int Client::close()
{
    closesocket(server);
    std::cout << "Server is closed" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Client main

```
#include "client.h"

#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include "opencv2\video\background_segm.hpp"
#include <opencv2\video\tracking.hpp>

#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

#pragma warning(disable: 4996)

#define FRAME_WIDTH 640
#define FRAME_HEIGHT 480

int imgSize;
int bytes = 0;
bool running = true;
int msg_size;

void VideoReceiver(Client client)
{
    while (running)
    {
        int IM_HEIGHT = FRAME_HEIGHT;
        int IM_WIDTH = FRAME_WIDTH;
        cv::Mat img = cv::Mat::zeros(FRAME_HEIGHT, FRAME_WIDTH, CV_8UC3);
        imgSize = img.total()*img.elemSize();

        const int ah = 921600;
        char sockData[ah];

        for (int i = 0; i < imgSize; i += bytes)
            if ((bytes = client.recvData(sockData + i, imgSize - i)) == 0)
                std::cout << "WTF" << std::endl;

        int ptr = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < img.rows; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < img.cols; ++j)
            {
                img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j) = cv::Vec3b(sockData[ptr + 0], sockData[ptr + 1], sockData[ptr + 2]);
                ptr = ptr + 3;
            }

        cv::namedWindow("Reveived_video", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        imshow("Reveived_video", img);
        char button = cv::waitKey(10);
        if (button == 'q')
        {
            std::cout << "Stop reveiving video data..." << std::endl;
            cv::destroyWindow("Reveived_video");
            client.close();
            break;
        }
    }
}

void message_sendind(Client client)
{
    while (true)
    {
        //receiv message
        int msg_size;
        client.recvData((char*)&msg_size, sizeof(int));
        char *msg = new char[msg_size + 1];
        msg[msg_size] = '\0';
        client.recvData(msg, msg_size);
        std::cout << "Message from server: " << msg
            << " (size: " << msg_size << ")"
            << std::endl;
        delete[] msg;

        //sending message
            //std::string msg1;
            //std::getline(std::cin, msg1);
            //int msg_size1 = msg1.size();
            //client.sendData((char*)&msg_size1, sizeof(int));
            //client.sendData(msg1.c_str(), msg_size1);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    Client client;
    client.open();

    std::thread th_video(VideoReceiver, client);
    
    while (true)
    {
    //receiv message
        int msg_size;
        client.recvData((char*)&msg_size, sizeof(int));
        char *msg = new char[msg_size + 1];
        msg[msg_size] = '\0';
        client.recvData(msg, msg_size);
        std::cout << "Message from server: " << msg
            << " (size: " << msg_size << ")"
            << std::endl;
        delete[] msg;

    //sending message
        std::string msg1;
        std::getline(std::cin, msg1);
        int msg_size1 = msg1.size();
        client.sendData((char*)&msg_size1, sizeof(int));
        client.sendData(msg1.c_str(), msg_size1);
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why the tag UDP when you are using TCP (`SOCK_STREAM`) ?

Comment: You cannot assume `recv(client, buffer, len, NULL);` will read `len` bytes. It could read less. You need to continue reading in a loop until all data is read, or an error occurs. (You *cannot* assume errors will not occur.)